# Use the Result of a SELECT STATEMENT as a VARIABLE

Tags: vba, ms-access, variables

I have the following code and it works just fine:

```
Dim result As Integer

result = 20

DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO ReportingTable (BUDGETPER1) VALUES (" & result & ");"
```

I don't really want to hardcode the 20 but rather populate using a SELECT statement:

```
select PD01 from SetVariables WHERE VariableType = 'HEADCOUNT' and BusinessUnit = 511
```

(the result of this SELECT statement is 20, I have tested it and it is fine)

What would be the easiest way of achieving this? I understand that in this specific example I would be able to achieve the desired result using Dlookup but I need to get my head around the concept of defining a variable with a select statement.

Comment: Would have to declare a recordset object variable, open recordset object, reference field of recordset. DLookup is less code.

Comment: Thank you. So it is definitely not possible without going the recordset route?

Comment: That's what I said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SELECT` query to determine the data to be inserted into your table:

```
Sub sInsertData()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO ReportingTable (BUDGETPER1) " _
        & " SELECT PD01 FROM SetVariables " _
        & " WHERE VariableType='headcount' AND BusinessUnit=511;"
    db.Execute strSQL
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

You could also then replace "headcount" and "511" with other values as required.

Regards,